# How to dismiss view when Tab bar item is pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view that has a navigation bar on the top, 4 buttons in the middle for the menu, and a tab bar navigation on the bottom.

When only the tab bar items are used everything works, but when I load one of the views via the button the view remains when the tab bar item is pressed.

I'm new to ios so I may not be explaining it that well.  I'm attaching a couple pictures to show what I mean.

[image: Initial Home Screen]
[image: Home Screen After Button Pressed, item on navigational stack]

I'm assuming that what I have to do to resolve is to intercept the Home button being pressed on the tab bar and tell it to dismiss the previously loaded view.   I could be out to lunch on this.

Please let me know how to make the home button on the tab bar load the initial view even if one of the buttons were pressed to load another view.

Here's what my storyboard looks like.  I used the Editor->Embed TabbarController.
[image]
[image]

** Update:  Still working on trying to resolve this.  I attempted to set the tab bar controller delegate via the app delegate as per some Q/A on stackoverflow but it didn't seem to make a difference.   There is another approach I should be taking if I want to have a main home screen with buttons to various sections and those sections have a navigation and Tab bar controllers?

Comment: please see your code  pressed tabbar item event

Comment: Can you show us the code where you load the new view (Videos/Performers/Games/Settings)?

Comment: I control dragged from the Video button to the VideoList View.  I didn't write any additional code except for a buttonPressed action that changed the selected tab to the video tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a line of code in tab bar item tapped event

Use popToRootViewController method here on the navigation controller of tab bar item.

You can find navigation controller object from tab Bar  like this

```
UINavigationController *navcon = (UINavigationController*)myTabBarController.selectedViewController;


the use popToRootViewController

[navcon popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

You can use this delegate for this code

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I obviously didn't implement your suggestion correctly. LOL

Comment: Here's what I added to my .m file: - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    UINavigationController *navcon = (UINavigationController*)tabBarController.selectedViewController;

    
    [navcon popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

Comment: code looks right. can you debug that your delegate is calling. if not then check delegate outlet in xib.

Comment: also check eric answer, may be you are using UITabBar rather than UITabBarController. so use the delegate which he points out.

Comment: No, it doesn't look like it's being called.  I just tried a NSLog and a breakpoint and neither were tripped.  The Tab bar and navigation were embedded via storyboards.  Does this make a difference?

Comment: Yes this makes the difference. You need to make connection between UITabBarController' Delegate and File's Owner.

Comment: I updated my question with screenshots of the Storyboard.  I also tried to make the connection from the tabbar controller's delegate in the connections inspector but it would not allow me to connect it to the File Owner.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it was very helpful in finding a solution.  What I did to solve the issue is posted below. :-)  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using UINavigationController for going to next view (Video) instead of using UITabBarController.

You should use TABBarController method.

Comment: I control dragged from the videos button to the videolist view.  I'm guessing this automatically used the navigation controller.  How do I make the button bring up the other view by still maintaining a working tab bar?

Comment: How do I use the Tabbarcontroller method when the button is pressed?

Comment: [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; should help. where 1 is tabindex .. start from 0

Answer (score 0):

If showing the video page on push .Then in ths selector action of the back button

add

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to esolve the issue but I had to start over. I used the tab bar application template to start.  Then on each view in the storyboard I selected "Editor->Embed->Navigation Controller". to add a navigation controller to each of the tab bar's views.    On the initial view I created buttons and control dragged from them to each of the views to link them.

I then updated the following files:

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface NRMAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabController.delegate = self;
    return YES;
}
```

MyViewController.m

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    UINavigationController *navcon = (UINavigationController*)tabBarController.selectedViewController;

    [navcon popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Also added an IBAction to the buttons to change the tab selected when the button is pressed.

```
- (IBAction)firstButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

I tested it on the simulator, iPhone 5, and iPod touch 3rd generation.